# c3p0 jdbc deadlock issue

Tags: jdbc, deadlock, c3p0

My application is based tomcat+spring+hibernate+mysql. tomcat version is 7.0.25, spring is 2.5, hibernate 3.0, mysql 5.1.53. the connection pool is c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar, the jdbc driver is mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.14-bin.jar. I encountered lots of deadlock in my application, especially when the table get larger. here I dump the stack of one deadlock by jprofiler:

Thread-1:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getCancelTimer()
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(int, com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer, boolean, boolean, com.mysql.jdbc.Field[ ], boolean) (line: 2146)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(byte[ ][ ], java.io.InputStream[ ], boolean[ ], int[ ], boolean[ ], boolean) (line: 2407)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(boolean, boolean)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate() (line: 105)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(org.hibernate.engine.QueryParameters, org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor) (line: 189)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(org.hibernate.engine.query.sql.NativeSQLQuerySpecification, org.hibernate.engine.QueryParameters) (line: 1190)
    org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate() (line: 357)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.dao.DaoHelper.executeUpdateFromSQLQuery(java.lang.String)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.dao.EventDao.deleteEventCountByUser(int) (line: 138)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.statistics.EventStatisticsService.collectEventCountInfoByUser(short, int, int) (line: 134)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.statistics.EventStatisticsService.collectEventCountInfo() (line: 78)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.statistics.EventStatisticsService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$23967f0c.invoke(int, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 149)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint()
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() (line: 149)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation) (line: 106)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[ ], net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy) (line: 635)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.statistics.EventStatisticsService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c70cea1b.collectEventCountInfo()
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke()
    org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(org.quartz.JobExecutionContext) (line: 260)
    org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(org.quartz.JobExecutionContext) (line: 86)
    org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run() (line: 216)
    org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run() (line: 549)
```

thread-2:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback() (line: 4711)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(boolean, boolean, boolean, java.lang.Throwable) (line: 4345)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close() (line: 1564)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(java.lang.Throwable) (line: 549)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close()
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(java.lang.Object) (line: 470)
    com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run() (line: 964)
    com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run() (line: 547)
```

the C3P0 configuration in tomcat server.xml is :

```
  <Resource type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
    jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/itms?max_sp_recursion_depth=10" 
    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" 
description="DB Connection" 
    name="jdbc/pooledDS" 
    driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="true" 
    auth="Container" 
    acquireIncrement="1" 
    acquireRetryAttempts="10" 
    idleConnectionTestPeriod="30" 
    initialPoolSize="15" 
    maxIdleTime="900" 
    maxPoolSize="50" 
    maxStatements="0" 
    minPoolSize="15" 
    numHelperThreads="10" 
    unreturnedConnectionTimeout="900" 
    user="root"
    password="admin" />
```

is my configuration wrong? please help

**another deadlock:**

Thread-3:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl, java.lang.String, int, com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer, int, int, boolean, java.lang.String, com.mysql.jdbc.Field[ ], boolean) (line: 2585)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setTransactionIsolation(int) (line: 5318)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setTransactionIsolation(int) (line: 701)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor223.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 74)
    $Proxy21.setTransactionIsolation(int)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.resetConnectionAfterTransaction(java.sql.Connection, java.lang.Integer) (line: 196)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(java.lang.Object) (line: 628)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus) (line: 989)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus) (line: 782)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus) (line: 701)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport$TransactionInfo) (line: 321)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation) (line: 116)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[ ], net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy) (line: 635)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069PeerService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2138ec73.authenticateDevice(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069AsyncServlet.processInform(javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage, com.aaabbbccc.intune.tr069.models.structs.HeaderStruct, java.lang.String) (line: 1527)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069AsyncServlet.processingSoapBody(javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody, javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage, com.aaabbbccc.intune.tr069.models.structs.HeaderStruct, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (line: 523)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069AsyncServlet.processSOAPMessage(javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (line: 387)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069AsyncServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (line: 194)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 722)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 305)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher$State) (line: 684)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.DispatcherType) (line: 593)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 530)
    org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$1.run() (line: 174)
    org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch() (line: 316)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 202)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 169)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 168)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 98)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(org.apache.coyote.Request, org.apache.coyote.Response, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) (line: 298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) (line: 1515)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) (line: 563)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() (line: 1600)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(java.lang.Runnable)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()
    java.lang.Thread.run()
```

thread-4:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getCancelTimer()
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(int, com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer, boolean, boolean, com.mysql.jdbc.Field[ ], boolean) (line: 2119)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery() (line: 2273)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery() (line: 76)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(java.sql.PreparedStatement) (line: 208)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(java.sql.PreparedStatement, boolean, boolean, org.hibernate.engine.RowSelection, org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor) (line: 1808)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor, org.hibernate.engine.QueryParameters, boolean) (line: 697)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor, org.hibernate.engine.QueryParameters, boolean) (line: 259)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor, java.lang.Object, org.hibernate.type.Type, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String, java.io.Serializable, org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister) (line: 1881)
    org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.io.Serializable) (line: 71)
    org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(java.io.Serializable, java.lang.Object, org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(java.io.Serializable, java.lang.Object, org.hibernate.LockMode, org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent, org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister, org.hibernate.engine.EntityKey, org.hibernate.event.LoadEventListener$LoadType) (line: 434)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent, org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister, org.hibernate.engine.EntityKey, org.hibernate.event.LoadEventListener$LoadType)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent, org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister, org.hibernate.engine.EntityKey, org.hibernate.event.LoadEventListener$LoadType) (line: 165)
    org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent, org.hibernate.event.LoadEventListener$LoadType) (line: 121)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(org.hibernate.event.LoadEvent, org.hibernate.event.LoadEventListener$LoadType) (line: 905)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(java.lang.String, java.io.Serializable) (line: 863)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize() (line: 95)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation() (line: 140)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 190)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.data.ProviderMaster_$$_javassist_23.getAutoApproveMode()
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069PeerService.authenticateDevice(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList) (line: 882)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069PeerService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$455c8769.invoke(int, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ])
    net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 149)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint()
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() (line: 149)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation) (line: 106)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[ ], net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy) (line: 635)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069PeerService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2138ec73.authenticateDevice(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069AsyncServlet.processInform(javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage, com.aaabbbccc.intune.tr069.models.structs.HeaderStruct, java.lang.String) (line: 1527)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069AsyncServlet.processingSoapBody(javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody, javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage, com.aaabbbccc.intune.tr069.models.structs.HeaderStruct, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (line: 523)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069AsyncServlet.processSOAPMessage(javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (line: 387)
    com.aaabbbccc.intune.web.peer.http.TR069AsyncServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (line: 194)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 722)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 305)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher$State) (line: 684)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.DispatcherType) (line: 593)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) (line: 530)
    org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$1.run() (line: 174)
    org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch() (line: 316)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 202)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 169)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 168)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 98)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) (line: 118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(org.apache.coyote.Request, org.apache.coyote.Response, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) (line: 298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) (line: 1515)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) (line: 563)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() (line: 1600)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(java.lang.Runnable)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()
    java.lang.Thread.run()
```

Comment: hi. so, it looks something bad is happening here. somehow a PreparedStatement actively in use belongs to a Connection c3p0 is preparing to destroy. i don't know how that happened, but it shouldn't happen. upgrading to c3p0-0.9.5-pre3 may fix the deadlock. c3p0-0.9.5-pre3 is more cautious than earlier versions about ensuring that a Connection is not in any sort of use before attempting to destroy it. but it may not help -- i think you really want to investigate how you retain a PreparedStatement of an effectively dead Connection in com.aaabbbccc.intune.dao.DaoHelper.executeUpdateFromSQLQuery.

Comment: Steve, thank you very much, I would try c3p0-0.9.5-pre3 and let you know the result. Actually, in my application, there are several deadlock at the same time, most of them are blocked at the same stacks. there are also some deadlocks which are blocked at other point of jdbc driver code. I will post it later.

Comment: @SteveWaldman  c3p0-0.9.5-pre3 doesn't help, there are still some deadlocks happened.

Comment: hi. the second deadlock indicates you have problems in the structure of your application. in this deadlock, both Threads are servlet client Threads that somehow have access to the same mysql Connection. that's bad--it suggests that maybe you are caching the Connection object in the servlet and letting multiple invocations of service() share that. don't do that. cache a reference to the DataSource in the ServletContext (application scope), or the the servlet, or in JNDI. then have each invocation of service() call getConnection(), so that each client acquires a Connection object as a local var.

Comment: use only this local, unshared Connection, then close() it prior to the service() method's return. be sure to close() reliably, in a finally block such that no prior Exception in the finally block can prevent the call.

Comment: @SteveWaldman I used Spring+hibernate to manage transactions and Connectons. I checked the source code, in thread-3, Spring wants to setTransactionIsolation at the beginning of method:authenticateDevice() [[@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false,
   rollbackFor={Exception.class},
   isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED,
   timeout=30)]] , In thread-4,ProviderMaster.getAutoApproveMode() is a lazy-loading in hibernate, ProviderMaster is a mapping Object in Hibernate.

Comment: i can't debug hibernate/spring stuff, not my area of expertise. but if more than one Thread at a time is working with a Connection, in practice you can expect problems (although in theory, the spec says Connections but not Statements or ResultSets should be robust to multithreaded access).